Creating a Multi-Page Invoice with Running Subtotal in Header
Problem Description
I'm trying to create a multi-page invoice using LaTeX with a specific requirement: every page (except the first) should display the subtotal of all previous pages in its header. The main challenge is that I don't know where the page breaks will occur in advance.
Current Approach
I've attempted a solution that almost works, but has a small issue. Here's what I've done so far:
I define a \subtotalafterline command after each line item, updating it with the cumulative total.
I use \fancyhead to display this subtotal in the header of the next page.
Current Issues
It seems to always include the first item from the next page in the subtotal (possibly because LaTeX evaluates it to determine the page break).
Minimal Working Example
Here's a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the issue:
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[myheadings]{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter

\global\newcommand{\subtotalafterline}{0}
\global\newcommand{\subtotalafterlastpage}{0}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[HR]{%
  Subtotal: \textbf{\subtotalafterlastpage}%
  \global\edef\subtotalafterlastpage{\subtotalafterline}%
}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields

\setlength{\headheight}{12.8064pt}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 0 \renewcommand{\subtotalafterline}{0}
  \item 1 \renewcommand{\subtotalafterline}{1}
  \item 2 \renewcommand{\subtotalafterline}{3}
  % ... more items ...
  \item 70 \renewcommand{\subtotalafterline}{2485}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

Full example with all 70 lines
Desired Outcome
I'm looking for a solution that:
Correctly calculates and displays the subtotal of all items from previous pages in the header.
Works even when items take up a variable number of lines.
Doesn't include items from the current page in the subtotal displayed in the header.
Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help :)
